# loosing data from device connected to serial port

Tags: python-3.x, serial-port, device, pyserial

I have a scale connected via USB (virtual serial port)

There is a print button to send the data, when I press the button fast enough 
I do not receive all the data.

The items stored in the list are ether not complete or, or empty

Looks like I do not get all the information

Here is full code:

```py
import serial
import time
import sys

x = []

def device_receave_data():
    try:
        z1serial = serial.Serial(port='COM6', baudrate=2400, bytesize=7, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,stopbits=2)
        if z1serial.is_open: # returns true or false
            print("port open")
            while z1serial.is_open:
                size = z1serial.inWaiting()

                if size:
                    data = z1serial.read(size)

                    dec_data = data.decode()
                    print(str(dec_data))
                    x.append(str(dec_data))
                    if len(x)>5:
                        break
                else:
                    time.sleep(0.1)

        else:
            print("not")

    except serial.serialutil.SerialException:
        print("not open")

device_receave_data()

for i in x:
    print('data ', i)

print(len(x))
```

Comment: What happens if you use a serial terminal?

Comment: with a serial terminal I receave the correct data output

Comment: What is the output of your program?

Comment: What does *I press the button fast enough* mean?

Comment: ifI press the button on the scale (to transmit the data) in a faster rate then my script dont receave all the data   /on the terminal software - the data that is displayed on scaale display